# iPad touchscreen stops recognizing touch

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-vice-city, nova-3

I recently bought an iPad 4 32gb Wifi. Whenever I play games like GTA: Vice City or Nova 3, which have analog sticks (most games are affected actually), it recognises my touch for sometime, but after a few seconds it doesn't recognize my touch. In GTA: Vice City whenever you touch the controls, it turns pink, but in my iPad it completely doesn't recognize my touch after a few seconds. It makes playing games like these impossible.

I have not jailbroken my iPad and my iOS version is 6.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have a lot of apps running in the background. 
Double click the home button to bring the current running apps, hold any of the icons till they shake and hit a red "X" mark and close all apps that you don't want. 
This should fix the problem.

Comment: Really? I don't see why this would make any difference at all

Comment: It removes all of the apps from memory. Theoretically, the system does this dynamically in the background as resources are needed, but it doesn't always work that way in practice. This is the iOS equivalent of "force-quitting" an app.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the app and that might help. If that fails I would restart the device itself. Most likely it's having trouble competing with other apps and can't get the resources it needs.